# fancybox content scrolls to anchor link in the popup

Tags: fancybox

Fancybox scrolls to any anchor link present in the popup content. Works fine when `href=""` is removed.

How to stop the jumping and stay on top of the popup content?

JiFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/qxgfsmyb/

JS:

```
$(".test").fancybox({
    autoCenter: true,
    smallBtn: false
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="" href="javasript:void(0);" data-fancybox data-src="#popup">test</a>
<div style="display: none;" id="popup">
<div class="popup-wrap">
<div class="popup-header">
<h4>Title</h4>

</div>
<div class="popup-text">
  <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde omnis nulla beatae, a aliquam voluptates eius voluptas corporis nostrum reiciendis dignissimos dolore quaerat vero dolor voluptatem laudantium, minus architecto quibusdam.</P>
  <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde omnis nulla beatae, a aliquam voluptates eius voluptas corporis nostrum reiciendis dignissimos dolore quaerat vero dolor voluptatem laudantium, minus architecto quibusdam.</P>
  <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde omnis nulla beatae, a aliquam voluptates eius voluptas corporis nostrum reiciendis dignissimos dolore quaerat vero dolor voluptatem laudantium, minus architecto quibusdam.</P>
  <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde omnis nulla beatae, a aliquam voluptates eius voluptas corporis nostrum reiciendis dignissimos dolore quaerat vero dolor voluptatem laudantium, minus architecto quibusdam.</P>
  <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde omnis nulla beatae, a aliquam voluptates eius voluptas corporis nostrum reiciendis dignissimos dolore quaerat vero dolor voluptatem laudantium, minus architecto quibusdam.</P>
  <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde omnis nulla beatae, a aliquam voluptates eius voluptas corporis nostrum reiciendis dignissimos dolore quaerat vero dolor voluptatem laudantium, minus architecto quibusdam.</P>
  <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde omnis nulla beatae, a aliquam voluptates eius voluptas corporis nostrum reiciendis dignissimos dolore quaerat vero dolor voluptatem laudantium, minus architecto quibusdam.</P>
  <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde omnis nulla beatae, a aliquam voluptates eius voluptas corporis nostrum reiciendis dignissimos dolore quaerat vero dolor voluptatem laudantium, minus architecto quibusdam.</P>
  <a href="">Test</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `autoFocus` option to toggle focusing on first focusable element, example:

```
$(".test").fancybox({
  autoFocus: false
});
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/z07bmf2w/